# Log Scale Contouring in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, contour, scale, batch

I have a shapefile of concentration values, they range from 0 7000. I want to either contour or display these in log scale (0.1, 1, 10, 100 and 1000) what is the best way of doing this?

I have about 200 files to batch process.

We have ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 Basic license with 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Is your data in raster format? If so, maybe use the raster calculator to do the log calculation, then make normal contours of the log-scaled raster.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS Pro, you can use the Contour List geoprocessing tool to specify the values that should be contoured. It uses a raster as input, so I first used TopoToRaster to get point data to a format that is contourable.